# Trying to override Woocommerce template files via a child theme

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, overriding

I did some changes in breadcrumb.php file.

When I add that file to here it works and override the woocommerce template.

```
/public/wp-content/themes/generatepress/woocommerce/global
```

but if I use child theme, it doesn't work.

```
/public/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/woocommerce/global
```

I tried to add this code to wp-config.php but didn2t help.

```
define('WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false);
```

Comment: Maybe it's a trivial question. Did you activate the child theme after adding the file to the respective directory?

Comment: Yes, I am already using childe theme. Thank you for reply.